# Using 3.5“ internal HDD connector for a internal 2.5” HDD

Tags: hard-drive, connector, voltage

I had a 3.5 inch internal HDD, and to connect it externally, I bought a 3.5 inch connector (as 3.5" HDD requires 12V power), which had a chip and external power adaptor - as 3.5 inch HDD can't run in 5V USB power. So, I actually plug the connector to external power and use the HDD.

I now have a internal 2.5" HDD. Can I use the 3.5" connector for this disk? I'm curious to know if it can tolerate the voltage as the power is connected from external source and the voltage is high.

The connector looks like this:
[image: The connector looks like this:]

I plug in the HDD to SATA port (power+data) and connect external power source to chip via adaptor, and use a cable to connect chip and machine (USB).

Comment: Without knowing anything about the product you purchased, I can only assume the product you purchased was designed exclusively for desktop 3.5" SATA storage devices.  It was not designed to work with 2.5" SATA storage devices.  *I personally wouldn't connect any storage device to that particular device in the screenshot.*

Comment: Alright, but I tried connecting a 2.5" drive, and it works. I'm unsure if that damage the drive due to high voltage.

Comment: Voltage is same for 3.5 and 2.5 drives, but 2.5 will consume less amperage, so yes it will work and is safe.

Comment: 3.5" hard drives require 12V and 5V for the motor and logic respectively.

Comment: You may refer [Power supply for 2.5'' HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/910103/power-supply-for-2-5-hdd?rq=1) and [Is it possible to connect a 3.5“ SATA drive to a 2.5” connector?](https://superuser.com/questions/1292574/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-3-5-sata-drive-to-a-2-5-connector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly OK.

2.5" SATA devices and 3.5" SATA devices are designed to be run from the same data and power connectors.
Many 2.5" devices don't actually use/need the 12V power wire, in which case they simply don't connect that pin on the connector to anything on their internal PCB.

That USB-SATA converter-board that you show in the picture is dangerous though.
If you accidentally bring it in contact with anything that is electrically conductive, while it is in use, you can potentially fry the board, the harddisk and even the USB port in the computer it is attached to.
And because it isn't shielded it may pickup radio-interference which (in the best case) causes re-tries when using it and (worst case) may cause data-corruption.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't get the conduction part. Can you elaborate? Also let me know what can I do to avoid it. Do I need any enclosure?

Comment: @unix_root A "naked" PCB, like that board, runs a high risk of electricity flowing where it isn't supposed to go (short circuit), via the material it is laying on/making contact with. A wooden table as in the photo is normally a very good insulator and it isn't a problem, but other materials (or your skin if you touch the board) could  have an effect. And humidity makes things worse as moisture usually increases conductivity. An enclosure isn't really needed, but you have to make sure you don't put the PCB in contact with any electrically conductive material when in use.

Comment: Alright, got you. The external power adaptor for the PCB actually outputs 12V --- 2A. And, as you said, I'll take extra care to ensure prevention of electrical conduction from via other sources. Thanks!